# Display only one layer of a costmap in rviz

Tags: navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a costmap with two layers (`static_layer` and `inflation_layer`) and I would like to be able to display them separately or in different colors because it is difficult to distinguish the two (there is only a very small difference in brightness between them) :

[image: image description]

Thanks in advance for your advices!

**[UPDATE]**

As advised by David Lu, I changed the `Color Scheme` of my costmap from `map` to `costmap`:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302689/display-only-one-layer-of-a-costmap-in-rviz/) by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not currently functionality to visualize layer by layer, but you can change the color scheme of the OccupancyGrid display in rviz to Costmap, which will make the color differences more apparent.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-09-07**:
Thanks, it's exactly what I needed. If I understand correctly, the purple zone corresponds to the real geometry of the obstacle and the light blue corresponds to place where the robot center can never be, whatever its orientation, right?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-09-11**:
That is correct.

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-09-11**:
Ok, thanks.

**Comment by [shawkontzu](https://answers.ros.org/users/86591/shawkontzu/) on 2022-09-23**:
Hi, if the light blue represents the inflation layer, what's the meaning of the dark blue layer? Thank!

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2022-10-06**:
The light blue comes from the inflation layer, but more things come from the inflation layer. Light blue/red/dark blue are different values in the actual costmap (253 down to 1)